# SQL Server : does order of full outer join matter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 4 full-outer joins in my query and its really slow, So does the order of `FULL OUTER JOIN` make a difference in performance / result ?

**FULL OUTER JOIN = ⋈**

Then,

I have a situation : A ⋈ B ⋈ C ⋈ D

All joins occur on a key common to all `k` contained in all A,B,C,D

Then:

- Will changing the order of ⋈ joins make a difference to performance ?
- Will changing the order of ⋈ change the result ?

I feel that it should not affect the result, but will it affect the performance or not I am not sure !

**Update:**

Will SQL Server automatically rearrange the joins for better performance assuming the result set will be independent of the order ?

Comment: The result should be the same. It's fairly easy to check the performence. Compare the time it takes when you order the tables from few to many hits to the reverse order.

Comment: Why not try it?  Look at the execution plans and SQL Profiler traces for the different combos?

Comment: When you say different order you mean: `(a FULL JOIN b) FULL JOIN c` vs `a FULL JOIN (b FULL JOIN c)` for example?

Comment: Yes and no. If you put the most restrictive first, the rest of the query will have less things to join up. But if you can't at least generally gaurantee that, tuning in that fashion won't be much use. We might be able to help you more if you post an the query plan (Just put Explain before the query and run it, then add teh vresuklt to your question). Might be better to look at why that many full outer joins are needed.

Comment: I have 100 thousand rows in the first table. And checking them will take hours. I want to understand will automatically do the re-arrangement for better performance ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, rearranging the JOIN orders should not affect the performance. MSSQL (as with other DBMS) has a [query optimizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimizer) whose job it is to find the most efficient query plan for any given query. Generally, these do a pretty good job - so you're unlikely to beat the optimizer easily.

That said, they do get it wrong occasionally. That's where [reading an execution plan](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) comes into play. You can add [JOIN hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx) to tell MSSQL how to join your tables (at which point, ordering *does* matter). You'd generally order from smallest to largest table (though, with a `FULL JOIN`, it's not likely to matter very much) and follow the [rules of thumb](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/16/702828.aspx) for join types.

Since you're doing `FULL JOINS`, you're basically reading the entirety of 4 tables off disk. That's likely to be very expensive. You may want to re-examine the problem, and see if it can be accomplished in a different way.

Comment: +1 : To the OP - It's important to note that SQL isn't executed natively and naively.  It's effectively just a an algorthmic expression to tell the optimiser the functional description of your problem.  The optimiser then effectively compiles it and executes a plan that can be considered to be almost completely independant of SQL.

Answer (score 4):

- Will changing the order of ⋈ change the result ?

No, the order of the `FULL JOIN` does not matter, the result will be the same. Notice however, that you can't use something like this (***the following may give different results depending on the order of joins***):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id) AS id,  --- Key columns used in FULL JOIN
    a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*                       --- other columns                 
FROM a 
  FULL JOIN b
      ON b.id = a.id
  FULL JOIN c
      ON c.id = a.id
  FULL JOIN d
      ON d.id = a.id ;
```

You have to use something like this (***no difference in results whatever the order of joins***):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id) AS id,   
    a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*                                   
FROM a 
  FULL JOIN b
      ON b.id = a.id
  FULL JOIN c
      ON c.id = COALESCE(a.id, b.id) 
  FULL JOIN d
      ON d.id = COALESCE(a.id, b.id, c.id) ;
```

---

- Will changing the order of ⋈ joins make a difference to performance?

Taking into consideration that the second and third joins have to be done on the `COALESCE()` of the columns and not the columns themselves, I think only testing with large enough tables will show if the indexes can be used effectively.

Comment: I don't have any coalesce situation. Also, see the update in the question !

Comment: @Yugal: WHat do youo mean with that? Can you post 2 versions of your query so we understand what you mean? How are you joining if you don't use `COALESCE()` ?

Comment: @Yugal: Then (as the first part of my answer says) you may have **different** results depending on the order of joins.

Comment: If you don't use the coalesce then you are mixing full outer joins and inner join depending on the order.  You need the coalesce's to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of a Full outer join shouldn't affect performance or results. The only thing that will be affected based on order of a Full Outer Join is the default order of the columns produced if using a SELECT *. You may be having performance issues simply from trying to do multiple joins with large tables. If there is no where clause to limit the tables, you could be going through hundreds of thousands of results.