# Does the order of tables in straight joins, with no hint directives, affect performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, informix

All SQL-based RDBMS' (versions up to 10 years old):

Does the order of tables in a straight join query (with no hint directives) make a difference for optimum performance and memory management? I heard that the last join should be the largest table. How does your DB's query optimizer handle this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684604/sql-server-does-order-of-full-outer-join-matter

Comment: Yes, especially on MySql. Though on some database it doesn't matter, I once ported an application that uses MySql to Postgresql, a slow query in MySql become faster in Postgresql. On MySql, I have to do different order of joining to make the query faster

Comment: @Yaroslav my question does not relate to outer joins, its full joins.

Comment: @MichaelBuen funny how different DB's optimizers work!.. yet their EXPLAINS don't really "explain" things like these!

Comment: Have you read only the title or full answers? You will see that your question is also answered as both questions end up dealing with same situation

Comment: My comment is an anecdote, but I forgot to blog it. So I just google some similar cases, here are what I've found: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,79125,79434#msg-79434 If your RDBMS is not very smart on figuring out the optimal order of join(joins which carries lesser intermediate rows), you have to override the join order yourself, e.g. http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_dbazine_oracle10g_dynamic_sampling_hint.htm In MySQL, in order for it to honor the order you join your tables, you shall use `STRAIGHT_JOIN`; in Oracle, you shall use this directive: `/*+ ORDERED */`

Comment: Despite the question being tagged 'Informix', most of the answers in this thread - even the 'ticked' one - are specific to other database technologies. Very odd.

Comment: @RET: I tagged Informix because its the SQL-DB I'm most familiar with, used it as an example to eval/compare against how other DB's differ in handling table ordering in straight-joins, plus was looking for Jonathan Leffler's input on this topic!.. I'm curious to find out how different DB's optimize based on table ordering, as well as other cost-based factors. Would be interesting to exactly know each DB's optimization rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add more on the subject... YES and NO, depends. That is my answer. It depends on many factors, wich RDBMS you are using (MySQL, MSSQL Server, Oracle, DB2...), type of join, size of tables (aka number of rows), indexes and more.

The previous answers says yes and no and appeal to using hints on the queries. But your question is:

> Does the order of tables in a join statement make a difference...

In my opinion, this leaves out the use of query hints as you are forcing the query optimizer to use the order prefered by you.

So, reusing the answer [posted on my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684604/sql-server-does-order-of-full-outer-join-matter) to your question, @Mark Brackett correctly points out that rearranging your joins (without query hints) does not affect the performance as the query optimizer will still use the most efficient execution plan for the present query. Maybe it will be not the most efficient so you can use hints and force to use the order you want on the joins and therefore modify the execution plan of the query.

More discussion on the subject on the following links:
[Does order matter in a JOIN clause?](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/29/60542.aspx)
[Optimize join methods](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/optimizerjoinmethods/1708/)

Comment: RE *"correctly points out that rearranging your joins (without query hints) does not affect the performance as the query optimizer"* Based on my firsthand experience with MySQL, re-arranging order of join can make the query faster even without the hints (I didn't know query hints then)

Comment: Based on one of the comment on http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/29/60542.aspx by Gian Maria, by inverting the order of 2 joins on Sql Server 2000, it makes her query faster (though on 2005 and 2008 it doesn't matter). Guess it depends on intelligence of the RDBMS and the version you are using. It's good if the RDBMS (and version) you are using is sophisticated enough to choose the optimal order for query execution regardless of table-joining order, you can focus more on your app logic

Comment: @MichaelBuen, you are just reaffirming what I say when you point out that "Guess it depends on intelligence of the RDBMS and the version you are using". That is why my answer is "Yes and No, depends" to the initial question, it depends in way too many factors.

Comment: True true :-) I just noticed the observation by Mark Brackett "rearranging your joins **(without query hints)** does **not affect** performance", some of my experience indicates otherwise, I just emphasize that **it does has an effect** even **without** the query hints (my MySql experience), I'm just re-affirming my experience and others(those who uses Sql Server circa 2000)

Comment: I think this can vary from one DB to another, depending on whether the query optimizer is cost-based or context-based, and how each DB's optimizer rules chooses the best query plan?

Comment: @FrankComputer a new stuff for me to learn RE: cost-based vs context-based (it's only now I see the phrase *context-based*, will google this later). Yes, it depends really on the query plan your RDBMS will choose; though if an RDBMS's query planner is a bit primitive, it won't be able to choose the best query plan for you, it will just do what you've told it to do, hence you won't get the best performance automatically, warranting manual intervention (e.g. re-arranging the joined tables) from you

Comment: Hmmm...same for me, "context-based optimization" in RDBMS is new for me. I know about it from semantic web and search by context but no relation with query optimizer on MSSQL Server, MySQL or Oracle. A lot can be found about query execution plan, how it is choosen, reused, etc. For example, on MSSQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105)

Comment: well, I say "context", but its actually heuristic!.. I remember benchmarking different queries which produce the same results with isql 2.10.06 and could see better performance when using specific patterns for my queries!.. sub-queries and OR's are expensive!

Answer (score 4):

Answer to your question - Yes,Order of the table make difference in join.

You can also let the optimizer know about execution plan.

The ORDERED hint causes Oracle to join tables in the order in which they appear in the FROM clause.

For example, this statement joins table TAB1 to table TAB2 and then joins the result to table TAB3:

```
 SELECT /*+ ORDERED */ TAB1.COL1, TAB2.COL2, TAB3.COL3
     FROM TAB1, TAB2, TAB3
    WHERE TAB1.COL1 = TAB2.COL1
         AND TAB2.COL1 = TAB3.COL1;
```

If you omit the ORDERED hint from a SQL statement performing a join, the optimizer chooses the order in which to join the tables. You may want to use the ORDERED hint to specify a join order if you know something about the number of rows selected from each table that the optimizer does not. Such information would allow you to choose an inner and outer table better than the optimizer could.

Usually, if you analyze the tables, the optimizer selects an efficient star plan. You can also use hints to improve the plan. The most precise method is to order the tables in the FROM clause in the order of the keys in the index, with the large table last. Then use the following hints:

```
/*+ ORDERED USE_NL(FACTS) INDEX(FACTS FACT_CONCAT) */
```

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

As far as Informix is concerned, anyway. The Optimiser will decide for itself what order to process the tables, and the order they appear in the `FROM` clause is of no consequence. *Unless you choose to override the default behaviour.*

You can use the `+ORDERED` hint to the Query Optimiser to force it to join the tables in the order they are presented in the `WHERE` clause, ie:

```
SELECT --+ORDERED 
       x.col1, y.col2, z.col3
  FROM z, y, x
  WHERE ...
```

forces the Optimiser to scan z, join to y, and join to x, *even if that creates an intermediate Cartesian product.* So it should be used with care.

---

*NB: This answer was written when the question was only tagged Informix, not multiple RDBMS technologies.*

Comment: Does an index, or the lack of one, on the joined columns affect the ordering of tables?

Comment: In general, this is accurate.  When dealing with Frank's questions, you need to be aware that some of the time he is asking about SE 4.10 on DOS, from circa 1989.  What you say would not be true for that.

Comment: @FrankComputer:  Yes, the presence or absence of indexes alters the way the query is executed.  That applies to both heuristic and cost-based optimizers (SE 4.10 uses a heuristic optimizer; other (more recent) versions of Informix databases use a cost-based optimizer).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, SE 4.10 DOS, also: SE 7.2 UNIX and 11.70.TC4DE (WinVista). I'm pretty sure 4.10 is cost-based, the docs say so plus EXPLAIN acts accordingly, although SE 2.10 is definitely heuristic! Anyway, just wondering whether its a good habit to construct joins like: 'smalltable.fk_id = bigtable.pk_id' or 'bigtable.indexedcolumn = smalltable.nonindexedcolumn' ?

Comment: Is the cost-based optimizer as old as 4.10?  It would probably have been in 4.00 too, if so.  Hmmm...memories get fuzzy after 20+ years.  The 'order' referred to is the the order in which the tables are listed in the FROM clause.  AFAIK, it has never mattered whether you write `A.col1 = B.col2` or `B.col2 = A.col1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that's a fair point, although since specific versions are not mentioned in this question, limiting my answer to only antediluvian ones seems appropriate :-)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: From 4.10.DC1 Release Notes: 'III. SE 4.10.DC1 SERVER CONCERN: It is particularly important to run the UPDATE STATISTICS command occasionally. You should use it frequently when there is a great deal of data manipulation occurring. This command updates the statistics used by the query optimizer. The query optimizer determines the most effective method for retrieving data from the database. Because the optimizer is cost-based, the statistics it uses (number of rows, minimum or maximum value in an index column, and so on) should be as up-to-date as possible.'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: My first exposure to Informix was in 1982, Informix 3.3 on an Altos 586 computer running Xenix 2.3.. Informix 3.3 (non-SQL) relied on READ vs. SELECT and was heuristic-based. ISQL 2.10.06 (1987) was also heuristic-based. The change to cost-based did not occur until ISQL 4.10.. ISQL 4.00 was still heuristic.

Comment: I agree that keeping to *post*-diluvian releases of Informix is a reasonable strategy in general.  With Frank, it is as well to be aware of the use of older versions too.  As ever, version information should be provided in the question, especially when the relevant releases cover a range of over 20 years.

Comment: Aha - I see you spotted my deliberate error, @JonathanLeffler o_O

Comment: There are many places in this world where, believe it or not, legacy software is still running!.. I have a couple of users who refuse to upgrade from DOS/ISQL 2.10 because its still fulfilling their requirements and it rarely breaks!.. Many enterprises and governments are still running COBOL, IMS, CICS code for their core production systems, so leaving out diluvian releases wouldn't be fair to this question. I'am interested in knowing how each SQL-DB handles their query optimization. It influences how one constructs a query, depending on the target DB.

Comment: @FrankComputer: when you want an answer to cover antediluvian as well as post-diluvian versions of the software (in any forum such as SO), you should identify the versions in which you are interested. Otherwise, people will assume (reasonably) that you are interested in nearly current releases (say those that are less than 5 years out of support), rather than older versions. I know your background and understand your viewpoint; not everyone has encountered your somewhat unusual circumstances. I know of no-one else using Informix software from before version 5.x (but I don't know everyone).

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that in the absence of a specific version or DB in my question, albeit the 'Informix' tag, that the majority of DB's currently being used are, up to 10 years old and Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.?.. So can also assume that most of them are cost-based?.. I'd be interested in knowing intricacies of how to best construct queries, based on how each one handles optimization, performance, etc. My particular circumstances are indeed unusual, so when I tagged Informix, don't assume I meant my circumstance, rather maybe from SE 7.2 and IDS 9.X to current releases?

Comment: Although I'm using several different versions of Informix: SE's 2.10, 4.10, 7.2 and Online 11.70, come to think of it, my ole clunkers SQL code is a lot more DB-portable than the newer versions because they don't have all the newer supersets which have been added over time!